# Joomla 1.5 module displaying code instead of widget

Tags: widget, joomla1.5

I need to add a widget within my website, which is based in Joomla. I have gotten the widget code and pasted it into the module manager, but instead of showing the widget, it started showing the code itself.

You can see the example of what I'm talking about [here](http://sysmind.com/vms/services).

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong, please, and help me figure out how to remove the code from displaying? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you pose the relevant code sections?  The more information you can give, the better the responses you will get.  Please see [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Did you write the code into the HTML-editor or into the WYSIWYG-editor? Are you sure this module is a widget (in Joomla it's called module) for code? I think we need more information.